# How do I shrink a partition from the beginning? i.e. create empty space at the beginning of the block device?

Tags: partition, embedded, sd-card, move-partition

I have devices with SD cards, with several partitions. The first partitions on the card is typically not mounted, and have vfat filesystem.

What I want to achieve is, to create a 1MB free space just before the partition, so I'd like to not just to resize the fs and partition, but also to align them to the end of the available space. I know some GUI based tools do that, but I need to do this on a minimal embedded system, using scripts or ssh connections.

The current map of the SD card (4GB) is.

16MB vfat
160MB squashfs
160MB squashfs
rest ext4

The idea is to preserve the structure but put raw u-boot at the beginning.

Comment: That would be helpful to know how many partitions, which type of file systems, sd card size, partitions sizes etc..